# Plotting several curves of the same variable for different values of a parameter

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, systems-biology

I am coding an SIR model using Mathematica. I would like to know how to plot multiple curves of I on the same figure for different values of the parameter beta, say for the values of 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, and 0.005. An example figure drawn using R is given below.

[image]

Given below is the code that I have been working with so far.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

equS = s'[t] == -beta*s[t]*i[t]
equI = i'[t] == beta*s[t]*i[t]-gamma*i[t]
equR = r'[t] == gamma*i[t]


beta = 0.001

gamma = 0.3


solution = NDSolve[{equS, equI, equR, s[0] == 9999, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0}, {s,i,r}, {t,100}];


solS=First[s/.solution];
solI=First[i/.solution];
solR=First[r/.solution];


Plot[solI[t], {t,0,100}, PlotRange -> {0,10000}, AxesLabel -> {"Time (Days)","Number of Infections (I)"}]
```

Any support on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) is the tool for the job, combined with `Table`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

equS = s'[t] == -beta*s[t]*i[t];
equI = i'[t] == beta*s[t]*i[t] - gamma*i[t];
equR = r'[t] == gamma*i[t];
gamma = 0.3;

solution = 
  ParametricNDSolve[
    {equS, equI, equR, s[0] == 9999, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0}, 
    {s, i, r}, {t, 100}, beta
  ];

Plot[
  Evaluate@
    Table[i[beta][t] /. solution, {beta, 0.001, 0.003, 0.0005}],
  {t, 0, 15},
  PlotRange -> {0, 10000},
  AxesLabel -> {
    "Time (Days)",
    "Number of Infections (I)"
  }
]
```

[image: plot required]

Comment: Could you please explain the piece of code "Table[i[beta][t] /. solution, {beta, 0.001, 0.003, 0.0005}]" and how it outputs the desired set of curves for beta = 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, and 0.005?